# Is the float to int cast the best solution to receive only integer number?

Tags: c#, casting, floating-point, language-agnostic

I don't care about the precision. I simply want the most optimized code in this example.
Example is:

- I'm counting a scale number by dividing one int type by one float type and by doing so i receive a float number. But actually i only want the integer part so i cast it to int type.
- but then in further calculation i need the number to be float. So again i need to cast it.

The question is: Is that the best way to do so? Is there a method that would trim this specific 'float' variable without casting and making a new one?

I tagged it language-specific because i am curious if other languages then c# would have some sort of method too. Another part of the question is i thing i don't really know what casting does here and i haven't found a good explanation yet.

Comment: Do you need value as an integer type or do you just need the integeral value ?
Math.Floor() and Math.Ceil() would round the number to integers, but the resulting time would be still float/double

Comment: After benchmarking `cast` and `Math.Floor` back to float, they are basically so close in terms of performance that they are indistinguishable, pick your favorite

Comment: So i think i am gonna stay with cast then. ty for benchmarking

Comment: @MatthewStrumiłło I had some issues with my first benchmarks, however I have updated the results. Anyway, good luck

Comment: "by dividing one int type by one float type" --> are either values ever negative?

Answer (score 2):

C# provides [Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netcore-3.1) to round to a nearest integer and [Math.Truncate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.truncate?view=netcore-3.1) to take the integer part (round toward zero).

> I don't care about the precision.

If you do not care about precision, use zero instead of the number. This provides an extremely fast result with no precision.

Answer (score 1):

Some [benchmarks](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet)

```
|   Method |           Job |       Runtime |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev | Ratio |
|--------- |-------------- |-------------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|------:|
|     Cast |    .NET 4.7.2 |    .NET 4.7.2 |  6.856 ms | 0.0858 ms | 0.0717 ms |  1.00 |
|     Cast | .NET Core 3.1 | .NET Core 3.1 |  6.799 ms | 0.0303 ms | 0.0269 ms |  0.99 |
|          |               |               |           |           |           |       |
|    Floor |    .NET 4.7.2 |    .NET 4.7.2 | 17.084 ms | 0.0708 ms | 0.0627 ms |  1.00 |
|    Floor | .NET Core 3.1 | .NET Core 3.1 | 22.654 ms | 0.0116 ms | 0.0091 ms |  1.33 |
|          |               |               |           |           |           |       |
| Truncate |    .NET 4.7.2 |    .NET 4.7.2 | 32.749 ms | 0.0411 ms | 0.0343 ms |  1.00 |
| Truncate | .NET Core 3.1 | .NET Core 3.1 | 32.803 ms | 0.0878 ms | 0.0821 ms |  1.00 |
```

**Tests**

<sub>***Note** this is not the most well thought-out test in the world, but it will at least give a basic comparison*</sub>

```
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net472, baseline: true)]
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.NetCoreApp31)]
public class Test
{

   private float[] _input;
   private float[] _result;

   public Test()
   {
      var rand = new Random(24);
      _input = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000000).Select(x => (float)rand.NextDouble()).ToArray();
      _result = new float[10000000];

   }

   [Benchmark]
   public void Cast()
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < _input.Length; i++)
         _result[i] = (float)_input[i];
   }

   [Benchmark]
   public void Floor()
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < _input.Length; i++)
         _result[i] = (float)Math.Floor(_input[i]);
   }

   [Benchmark]
   public void Truncate()
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < _input.Length; i++)
         _result[i] = (float)Math.Truncate(_input[i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `double d = Math.Floor(a / b);`, but it will return `double`.